# Output console issue with Heroku and Github on vscode

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, heroku

I got a problem with vscode and Github extension, I have a discord bot who runs on heroku, but everytime I write on save my code (without pushing it) it sends and focus this error, so I can't write and I need to clck on my code to continue :/

Any ideas to solve this issue ?

```
git symbolic-ref -q HEAD
git for-each-ref --format='%(upstream)' 'refs/heads/master'
git config --local --get remote.origin.url
git config --local --get-regexp ^remote.*.url
Command failed: git config --local --get remote.origin.url


Error: Command failed: git config --local --get remote.origin.url


    at makeError (C:\Users\Stanislas\.vscode\extensions\knisterpeter.vscode-github-0.30.1\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at module.exports.Promise.all.then.arr (C:\Users\Stanislas\.vscode\extensions\knisterpeter.vscode-github-0.30.1\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16)
    at <anonymous>


Your configuration contains an invalid remoteName. You should probably use one of these:

heroku
```

Comment: So address the error that is clearly indicated in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to bother everyone, I disable the extension, he wasn't compatible with heroku